# Switch case tratando diferente 1 e "1"

Tags: javascript, tipagem, switch, case

Uma variável que armazena o número 1 é igual a uma variável que armazena o texto “1”?

```js
const q = 1;
 
switch (q) {
    case '1':
        answer = "Texto 1";
        break;
    case 1:
        answer = "Número 1";
}
console.log(answer);
```

Por qual motivo o código em JavaScript imprime a mensagem “Número 1” ao invés de ”Texto 1”?

Comment: Complementando as respostas: conforme descrito na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#description) e na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-caseclauseisselected), as comparações feitas em cada `case` usam o operador `===`, que compara não só o valor, mas também o tipo (é diferente do `==`, que faz coerção de tipos, ou seja, `'1' == 1` é verdadeiro, mas `'1' === 1` é falso)

Answer (score 6):

> Uma variável que armazena o número 1 é igual a uma variável que armazena o texto “1”

Não, não é. Cada variável armazena o dado de forma completamente diferente de acordo com seu tipo, eles não são a mesma coisa. JavaScript permite armazenas valores de qualquer tipo em todas as variáveis, ou seja, a variável não tem tipo (tecnicamente ela tem um único tipo, mas isso não vem ao caso agora), mas os valores possuem tipos normalmente. Isso é chamado de tipagem dinâmica, e tem vantagens e desvantagens.

JavaScript é uma linguagem que adotou a filosofia de tipagem fraca, ou seja, sempre que alguma situação exigir um dado de um tipo a regra da linguagem tenta fazer o dado existente se adequar ao dado que está sendo necessário. E isso é feito de forma inconsistente na linguagem. Mesmo consistente é considerado defeito da linguagem e as vantagens não compensam as desvantagens, mas de forma inconsistente fica pior.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre a tipagem porque não é o foco da pergunta e já tem diversas respostas no site sobre o assunto de forma completa.

O `switch` é uma instrução de *jump table*, ou seja, ele tem uma tabela com vários valores e de acordo com o valor que está buscando ele cai em um dos elementos dessa tabela ou eventualmente em um elemento especial que é o tratamento para o caso de não achar equivalência na tabela, o tal do `default`. E assim o que será executado é de acordo com o que acha nessa tabela.

No exemplo da pergunta a tabela tem dois dados completamente diferentes, até porque seus tipos são diferentes. Quando a execução vai fazer a seleção ele procura na tabela um dado que seja estritamente equivalente ao que está querendo comparar. Se não achar ele cai no `default`, ou faz nada se este não existir um `default`, o que é o caso.

Este é um caso que a linguagem preferiu não tentar transformar o dado em algo usável, inconsistentemente com vários outros usos equivalentes. Inclusive se tirar o segundo `case` não cai no primeiro:

```js
switch (1) {
    case '1':
        console.log("Texto 1");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/SwitchWeak.js).

A regra adotada no `switch` não é da tipagem fraca, ao contrário de outros pontos, portanto, o `switch` funciona com comparação estritamente igual, como se usasse o `===`.

Por esse e diversos outros motivos JavaScript é considerado por muitos programadores uma linguagem ruim e causa urticária nos *fanboys* da linguagem.

Sabendo desses todas essas regras, que tornam a linguagem nada fácil, ao contrário da crença popular, dá para usar a linguagem normalmente, e até sem surpresas depois de ter bastante experiência.

Comment: Agora encontrei uma ótima usagem pra switch. Então ao não transformar o valor, o case seria igual ao if com a comparação de 3 iguais ===?

Comment: @ruansenadev bem a grosso modo, sim.

Answer (score 2):

*"Uma variável que armazena o número 1 é igual a uma variável que armazena o texto “1”?"*

A resposta é **não**, os valores são de tipos diferentes.

Primeiro, é preciso conhecer os tipos básicos no `javascript`: [Estruturas de dados](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

> Sete tipos de dados são: primitives:
>
> - Boolean
> - Null
> - Undefined
> - Number
> - BigInt
> - String
> - Symbol
> - e Object

Como o próprio exemplo do link acima mostra, 1 é um *Number* e "1" é uma *String*, logo os resultados são diferentes.

Isso já responde a sua segunda pergunta:
*Por qual motivo o código em Javascript imprime a mensagem “Número 1” ao invés de ”Texto 1”?*: porque quando declara a variável assim `const q = 1;` ela é "tipada" como  número. Isso é tipagem dinâmica referenciada no link acima:

> **Tipagem Dinâmica**
> JavaScript é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Isso significa que você não necessita declarar o tipo de uma variável
> antes de sua atribuição. O tipo será automaticamente determinado
> quando o programa for processado

Ou seja ao comparar o valor usando o comando `swith`, o valor declarado é do tipo "Number", logo cai na segunda opição do case, onde o valor também é um "Number".

É mais fácil de perceber isso usando o pperador [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) do `javascript`:

```js
var v1 = 1;
var v2 = "1"

console.log("typeof v1=" + typeof v1);
console.log("typeof v2=" + typeof v2);
```

Note que os tipos se comportam de maneiras diferentes, ou seja, se usar o operador de soma entre *Numbers* e *Strings*, temos diferentes resultados:

```js
var v1 = 1;
var v2 = "1"

// soma de dois Numeros
var v3 = v1 + v1;
// soma de duas strings
var v4 = v2 + v2;

console.log("v3=" + v3);
console.log("v4=" + v4);

console.log("==========");

console.log("typeof v3=" + typeof v3);
console.log("typeof v4=" + typeof v4);
```

Em resumo, de uma forma muito grosseira, seria como comparar 1 e "um"

Answer (score -5):

Dando uma resposta curta e grossa que servirá para a maioria das linguagens que você trabalhar.

Valor entre aspas é uma string e número sem aspas é número mesmo.

No caso do JS o número é simplesmente tratado como number, mas para outras linguagens você ainda terá a tipagem com int e float (valor com número inteiro ou ponto flutuante)

A caso de curiosidade, se você colocar uma letra sem as aspas sinalizando que é uma string você terá como retorno o valor daquela letra na tabela ASCII, lembrando que dependendo da linguagem poderá resultar em um erro e mesmo que funcione é uma péssima prática de programação.

Comment: _"Valor entre aspas é uma string e número sem aspas é número mesmo."_ isso pode confundir o OP quando usar qualquer literal sem estar em aspas, como `true, {}, 0x1c, null, undefined...` ou nomes de variáveis. É legal complementar isso explicando o que é uma expressão de fato. Também é perigoso afirmar que essa regra _servirá para qualquer linguagem_.

Comment: Tem razão, acabei esquecendo de citar outras situações e palavras reservadas das linguagens, obrigado por complementar!

Comment: Apesar de bem intencionado o silogismo hipotético **do porque serviu em uma linguagem deverá funcionar em outra** é contraválido e pode levar nossos leitores menos experientes a erros. A presunção de similaridade léxica é equivalência  sintática é uma das causas de prejuízos no meio corporativo.

Comment: Como exemplo prático em linguagem [tag:c] a tentativa de operar dois literais entre aspas, `'A' e '!'`, por meio do operador `+` que deveria funcionar análogo 
a [tag:javascript] onde expressão `'A' + '!'` resulta em `A!` mas não é o que acontece pois cada linguagem entende seus literais de forma diferente. Veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/3579ZU